# Content script not working in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a small chrome extension that I am testing

Here I have background.js content-script.js but I see content-script.js is available in final build but thats not working as expected meaning not even the console.

Its available in build
Manifest.json has the correct details about content script
Manifest.json version is 3

https://github.com/swam1j77/chromeext

[image: package_screenshot]

Let me know if you need more details

How to get the content-script working and interacting with the webpages

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Sample Extension",
"version": "0.1.0",
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"icons": {
    "16": "./icons/icon-16x16.png",
    "36": "./icons/icon-36x36.png",
    "48": "./icons/icon-48x48.png",
    "120": "./icons/icon-120x120.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content-script.js"
        ]
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "inject-script.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
],
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "PerfWatch"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "background"
]
```

}

Comment: We'll need to see the code responsible for injecting the content script into the webpage - either the `"content_scripts"` key of manifest.json, or the JavaScript code using the `chrome.scripting` API.

Comment: Added the manifest.json

Comment: You need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.